# How to use \toks with \foreach

Tags: programming

I would like to use `\foreach` to replace the next code :

```
\def\x{0}
\edef\y{\x}     
\xdef\z{(b\y)}       

\def\x{1}
\edef\y{\x}
\xdef\w{\z(b\y)}     

\def\x{2}
\edef\y{\x}
\xdef\z{\w(b\y)}  

\def\x{3}
\edef\y{\x}
\xdef\w{\z(b\y)}     
\w
```

The aim is to get this result : (b0)(b1)(b2)(b3) with a macro

I got the result with `\toks` but perhaps it's possible to avoid this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\toksdef\toks@=0 %  ?
\toksdef\toks@@=1 % 
\xdef\tmp{}%

\foreach \x in {0,1,2,3}{%
    \toks@\expandafter{\x}%
    \toks@@\expandafter{\tmp}%
    \xdef\tmp{\the\toks@@(b\the\toks@)}%
 }
\makeatother 
\tmp
\end{document}
```

I think this code is not nice. What is the better way to get the result without an extern package ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The LaTeX kernel provides `\@for` that doesn't work in groups like `\foreach`:

```
\def\tmp{}
\@for\next:=0,1,2,3\do{\edef\tmp{\tmp(b\next)}}
```

In your code there's no need for `\toks`:

```
\foreach \x in {0,1,2,3}{%
    \xdef\tmp{\tmp(b\x)}%
 }
```

would work as well.

However, if the items are "dangerous" in the sense that they don't survive `\edef` (like `\textbf` or other similar tokens), using token registers is necessary for avoiding complete expansion and your way is good. It's better to use `\toks2` and not `\toks1` for local assignments, so you should do

```
\toksdef\toks@@=2
```

Comment: yes I know that but I would like to use `\foreach` because I used often `\foreach` and I like some options of this macro.

Comment: @AlainMatthes If you don't want to use an external package you don't have `\foreach`.

Comment: :)  ! I wanted to say only `pgffor` and not another package. I load always tikz in my works also I can work with pggfor and pgfkeys.

Answer (score 11):

Using a big package loop structure is really overkill for this, as a single `\def` is enough

```
\def\x#1{\ifnum\numexpr#1\relax>0 \x{#1-1}\fi(b\the\numexpr#1\relax)}

\typeout{\x{3}}
```

produces

```
(b0)(b1)(b2)(b3)
```

Comment: Very interesting and efficient but the loop structure (here foreach ) is useful  for other tasks.

Comment: @AlainMatthes usefulness is a very over-rated concept:-)

Comment: I can share this point of view :)

Answer (score 7):

If you are using `pgfkeys` and `pgffor` (which is internally used by the `.list` handler), you can simply use the `.list` handler.

If you only need the sequence `(b0)(b…)b(3)` typeset, you can set up *one* `.code` key and use that key with the `.list` handler. (→ `do`)

However, if you want to have an expandable macro, this macro has to be fixed (→ `doo`, equivalent to `\foreach \x in {0,...,3}{\xdef\tmp{\tmp(b\x)}}`) or you need more than one key (→ `dooo`, more flexible).

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys,pgffor}
\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{/alain/do/.code=(b#1)}
\pgfkeys{/alain/doo/.code=\edef\tmp{\tmp(b#1)}}
\pgfkeys{/alain/dooo ini/.code=\let\qrr@doo@temp\pgfutil@empty,
         /alain/dooo/.code=\edef\qrr@doo@temp{\qrr@doo@temp(b#1)},
         /alain/dooo set/.code=\let#1\qrr@doo@temp}
\makeatletter
\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{/alain/do/.list={0,...,3}}

\def\tmp{}
\pgfkeys{/alain/doo/.list={0,...,3}}
\tmp

\pgfkeys{/alain/.cd,
         dooo ini,
         dooo/.list={0,...,3},
         dooo set=\myTemp}
\myTemp
\end{document}
```

Comment: I like very much this code. Awesome ! I need to learn more profoundly pgfkeys