# Multiple labels with "node label"

Tags: tikz-pgf

I make some experiments with `\pgfkeys` after the Qrrbrbirlbel's answer to this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107414/how-to-use-toks-with-foreach)

The first try is :

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{/swatch/.code={\node[fill=white] at (m.90-30*#1) {#1};}}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[circle,minimum size=4cm,draw] (m) {};
    \pgfkeys{/swatch/.list={1,...,12}}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and the result is :

[image]

`\foreach` is very fine to get the same result but It was funny to try.

Now I would like to know if it's possible to do something like this to add multiple labels

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[circle,minimum size=4cm,draw,label=90:12,label=0:3,label=-90 :6,label=-180:9] (m) {};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Code

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter % http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/106796/16595
\tikzset{anchor/.append code=\let\tikz@auto@anchor\relax}
\makeatother
\tikzset{
    clock hours/.style={
        label={[fill=white,anchor=center]-(30*#1-90):#1}}
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[circle,minimum size=4cm,draw,clock hours/.list={1,...,12}] (m) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Very fine, I am very impressed with your speed and style of your answers

Comment: @AlainMatthes I’ll try my best. Though, I just noticed that TikZ *does* evaluate the angle parameter of the label key anyway, so we can just use `label={[…]-(30*#1-90):#1}`. No need for a `.code` handler.